# Autodesk Forge [GET] /activities/:id always returns null

Tags: autodesk, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm working on the [step-by-steptutorial Design automation for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/). I'm trying to get the [[GET] /activities/:id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/activities-id-GET/) to work to get detailed info of an activity. At first, I retrieved all the activities available to me:

[image]

When I try to call the [GET] /activities/:id with any of the activities except for the first one, I receive a json with detailed info of the activity. That works just fine. But when I try to do the same with the first activityId "GZZQ.....DeleteWallsActivity+$LATEST" I consequently receive a "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".

I tried this with no encoding:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/activities/GZZQabcdefghijklmnopqrNroJTafTze.DeleteWallsActivity+$LATEST

and with HttpUtility.UrlEncode:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/activities/GZZQabcdefghijklmnopqrNroJTafTze.DeleteWallsActivity%2b%24LATEST

But the result is the same: the (400) bad request error. Has anyone any idea why this doesn't work?

Environment: Visual Studio 2019, C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the document at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/aliases-and-ids/ it mentioned the purpose of $LATEST alias:

For every AppBundle and Activity, the system always creates a special Alias named “$LATEST”. The main purpose of this Alias is for listing AppBundles and Activities. It can also be used in

- [GET] /appbundles/:id/aliases/$LATEST
- [GET] /activities/:id/aliases/$LATEST

calls. Note however, that **it must not be used in other calls where an Alias (as part of fully qualified id, see later) is expected**. You must use the real Alias that you created for the AppBundle or the Activity in those calls.